# -R not working with chmod?

Tags: bash, chmod

I was asked to make all the HTML files I own have these permissions: RW-RW-R-- (so 664 I believe, currently they are 644).

So I ran this:

```
$ chmod -R 664 *.html
```

And it only changed the html files that were in that folder (I went to a sub folder and checked permissions there, they did not change). I need to change all of the files I have so I ran this from the top level folder.

Is my command wrong? Is it some server setting? I believe I have done this before, but I can't get it to work now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the command:

```
chmod -R 664 *.html
```

The shell will expand the file paths given (`*.html`) and operate just on those. That would be all html files in the current directory. It won't traverse directories unless you have one that matches that pattern, and in that case, everything under that folder would be changed.

To do what you want to do, you need to use `find`:

```
find . -name "*.html" -exec chmod 664 {} \;
```

If the html files you want to change are only one or two levels down, you could do something like this:

```
chmod 664 *.html */*.html */*/*.html
```

etc. But `find` would be the general solution.

Comment: Thank you, This worked and it's nice to know about the additional folder arguments. I will accept when I can.

Comment: `find . -name \*.html -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 664` also works, and invokes `chmod` just once (or a few times) for multiple files. (Joachim Isaksson posted that as answer and then deleted it for some reason.)

Comment: Thanks @KeithThompson. I usually just type the shorter version since performance at that level isn't always a concern. I suppose Joachim deleted his answer because it was visibly longer. But I agree: it provided a valuable alternative.